# Databases that Handle Many Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm considering converting some excel files I regularly update to a database. The files have a large number of columns. Unfortunately, many of the databases I am looking at, such as Access and PostreSQL, have very low column limits. MySQL's is higher, but I'm worried that as my dataset expands I might break that limit as well.

Basically, I'm wondering what (open source) databases are effective at dealing with this type of problem.

For a description of the data, I have a number of excel files (less than 10) with each containing a particular piece of information on some firms over time. It totals about 100mb in excel files. The firms are in the columns (about 3500 currently), the dates are in the rows (about 270 currently, but switching to a higher frequency for some of the files could easily cause this to balloon).

The most important queries will likely be to get the data for each of the firms on a particular date and put it in a matrix. However, I may also run queries to get all the data for a particular firm for a particular piece of data over every date.

Changing dates to a higher frequency is also the reason that I'm not really interested in transposing the data (the 270 beats Access' limit anyway, but increasing the frequency would far exceed MySQL's column limits). Another alternative might be to change it so that each firm has its own excel file (that way I limit the columns to some amount less than 10), but is quite unwieldy for the purposes of updating the data.

Comment: Database: You're Doing It Wrong.  One column for dates, one column for Firm name.  NORMALIZATION.  Read about it.

Comment: I wish I could up-vote the above comment more than once.  Seriously, a database is not a dumping ground for data.  You need to *model* your data into meaningful related entities.  One column per firm?  One table per firm?  These are all clear and significant design flaws.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Just to be clear, you'd be saying to have like 3500*270=945000 rows with the dates repeating for each firm. Like (for two firms and two dates with ... as separating rows) date1 firm1 value...date2 firm1 value...date1 firm2 value...date2 firm2 value.

Comment: This is why databases like Access don't have a lot of columns.  ;o)  When a database is designed properly, you should only have a couple dozen columns at most in each table.  But you can have as many rows as you want (I've worked with tables with over 2 billion) and just filter the data when you want to report on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be begging to be split up!

How using a schema like:

```
Firms
  id
  name

Dates
  id
  date

Data_Points
  id
  firm_id
  date_id
  value
```

This sort of de-composed schema will make reporting quite a bit easier.

For reporting you can easily get a stream of all values with a query like

SELECT firms.name, dates.date, data_points.value from data_points left join firms on firms.id = data_points.firm_id left join dates on dates.id = data_points.date_id

Comment: `date_id`? Seriously?

Comment: Why not? Since he decided to make the dates the rows in the original spreadsheet I'm assuming that it is desireable to link all the datapoints to a given date directly instead of e.g. storing a datetime in the data_points table. Sure, you could simply this, but in the absence of any further details I chose to keep the integrity of the source data fully intact. For instance, imagine if you find that one of the dates is wrong, with this schema this will make the exact same change as editing the first cell of the row in excel, whereas if you store dates directly with the data that won't happen.

Comment: @TylerEaves I think this answer is similar to what Johnny Bones listed in his comment above. No matter what, it seems I'd need to convert the current excel files into a format that works with this approach before proceeding. I guess I would need to separate what is convenient for updating the data (the excel files) from formatting the data for use in the database (python probably) and subsequent analysis (whatever is appropriate).

Comment: You might consider looking at xlrd (http://www.python-excel.org/) which will allow you to read Excel files in python directly. You might be able to use that and skip the database entirely. You use the xlwt module to write back to the original sheet too.

Comment: I've been using pandas, which I think uses xlrd at a low level. Pandas has a to_sql function, though I haven't been able to get it to work yet (likely because I had too many columns or something else related to the issues we have discussed).